# enabledRemoteNotificationTypes return invalid value

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

Hi I am using `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` as I am targeting iOS 7 only.

But i observed that, if I set notifications to `none` and deletes app & then re install, I found that even in notification settings my option is selected other that none, `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` method returns me value `3`, which is kind of weird.

This is what i tried:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationType = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
// will return YES if "Alert Style" is set to "Banners" or "Alerts"
if (notificationType & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
    returnVal = YES;
} else {
    returnVal = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS caches those settings in a fairly annoying way I believe. The only way to truly reset it on the simulator is to reset its content and settings so you get a clean slate.

On a physical device you have to do a dance with adjusting the time as [outlined](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42) on the ADC Site.

1. Delete your app from the device.
2. Turn the device off completely and
   turn it back on.
3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the
   date ahead a day or more.
4. Turn the device off completely again and
   turn it back on.

Comment: Hey Justin thanks for your answer, but i have a different situation.
I need the reset of "cached" settings programatically.
Anyways thanks again :)